# Treat Macro Argument as Hex Number

Tags: symbols, unicode

I’m writing a macro to output Unicode codepoints in the `U+1F642  SLIGHTLY SMILING FACE` format. To do this, I need to print an argument as a hex number as well as pass it to `\symbol`.

Minimal non-working example:

```
\newcommand{\unicode}[3][]
    {\texttt{U+#1} {#3 \symbol{"#1}} \texttt{#2}}
```

I think some `\expandafter` or counter magic is required, but I’m not exactly sure where to go.

I can assume the codepoint will always be in upper-case hexadecimal, so multiple number-formats don’t need to be accounted for.

If it makes a difference, I’m using XeLaTeX.

The error is unsurprising:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   {
\\unicode [#1]#2#3->\texttt {U+#1} \symbol {"#1}
                                                 \texttt {#2}
```

Comment: Your error message doesn't match up with the definition you've given: please post a full example.

Comment: @JosephWright OK, done; the definition includes a third optional argument for switching the symbol font, in case a special font is needed for a particular codepoint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\char` is a TeX primitive that takes as argument a `<number>` and *doesn't* want braces as delimiters of the argument.

LaTeX provides `\symbol` as a wrapper around it.

```
\newcommand{\unicode}[2]{%
  \texttt{U+#1} \symbol{"#1} \texttt{#2}%
}
```

With `\char` it should be

```
\newcommand{\unicode}[2]{%
  \texttt{U+#1} \char"#1\space\space\texttt{#2}%
}
```

(the first `\space` is gobbled as the `<number>` terminator, the second one is typeset).

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\newcommand{\unicode}[2]{%
  \texttt{U+#1} \symbol{"#1} \texttt{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\unicode{0180}{LATIN SMALL LETTER B WITH STROKE}

\unicode{04AF}{CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER STRAIGHT U}

\end{document}
```

However, if you want to be able to specify a different font for some character, the definition can be as follows. Note the order of the arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\newfontfamily{\djvusans}{DejaVu Sans}

\newcommand{\unicode}[3][]{%
  \texttt{U+#2} {#1\symbol{"#2}} \texttt{#3}%
}

\begin{document}

\unicode{0180}{LATIN SMALL LETTER B WITH STROKE}

\unicode{04AF}{CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER STRAIGHT U}

\unicode[\djvusans]{1F0CA}{PLAYING CARD TEN OF DIAMONDS}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the optional argument to be last (but I don't recommend it), you can use `\NewDocumentCommand`, provided by `xparse` which is loaded by `fontspec`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\newfontfamily{\djvusans}{DejaVu Sans}

\NewDocumentCommand{\unicode}{mmO{}}{%
  \texttt{U+#1} {#3\symbol{"#1}} \texttt{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\unicode{0180}{LATIN SMALL LETTER B WITH STROKE}

\unicode{04AF}{CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER STRAIGHT U}

\unicode{1F0CA}{PLAYING CARD TEN OF DIAMONDS}[\djvusans]

\end{document}
```

Comment: While I do appreciate your prompt response, this doesn’t actually work — the issue is with the expansion order (i.e. `\char`/`\symbol` not actually receiving a number), rather than syntax. I’ve revised the question to match, however.

Comment: @9999years You are numbering arguments in the wrong order.

Comment: Ah, shoot! Should’ve looked at the argument order. Sorry for the terseness, I appreciate the help.